# Swap two subtraction values

Tags: vim, vi

Something I regularly do in Vim needs to go. I'll do a subtraction

```
var a = b - c;
```

run it and realize it should be

```
var a = c - b;
```

What's the most efficient way to spin two values around a minus sign in vim?

Answer (score 1):

Found it (kinda)

```
noremap <F2> :s/\([^ -]*\)\([ ]*\)-[ ]*\([^;]*\);/\3 - \1;/<CR>:nohl<CR>
```

stolen from

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swap_LHS_and_RHS_of_an_Assignment_statement

Move along, nothing to see here.

Comment: That's a nice trick, I only wonder why three matched patterns are saved when only two are used and the command is equivalent to :s/\([^ -]*\)[ ]*-[ ]*\([^;]*\);/\2 - \1;/

Answer (score 1):

You could try [SwapText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4971).

When comparing to the solution based on the substitute command (`:s//`) it has the advantage of being applicable to any kind of text swapping, not only mathematical expressions, and it can be applied to expressions that span in multiple lines. It can also correct any of the values, i.e., it is not restricted to the first minus sign of an expression.

On your example you could delete `b` using any regular command, such as `dw` or `x`, then move over `c` and type `<leader>` (which is usually `\`) followed by `x` and a motion (e.g.: `l` or `w`).

Answer (score 1):

The is a wonderful [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode on this very subject: [Swapping two regions of text with exchange.vim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/swapping-two-regions-of-text-with-exchange-vim/). The screencast talks about using Tom McDonald’s [exchange.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) to make a selecting two regions to be exchanged.

Your example would be done via:

```
fbcxlfccxl
```

Exchange.vim uses `cx{motion}` to mark text to be exchanged. In the example above use use the motion `l` to select both the `b` and the `c`. You however can use whatever motion fits the need. You can also use a visual selection.